# jQuery Buttons Click issue

Tags: jquery, button

I have some code html:

```
    <button>click 1</button>
    <button>click 2</button>
```

And jQuery code :

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            console.log('yeah');
            $(this).siblings().on('click');
            $(this).off('click');
        });
    });
```

Something I wish:

- First, click **button 1** to say **"yeah"**
- Second, click **button 1 again** and nothing happen
- It'll be happy for **button 1** (not button 2) to say "yeah" again, **only** when I click **button 2** then come back to
  click on **button 1**

it 's also the same instead of first, I click on **button 2**
But I wonder why it don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are looking for this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").on('click', handleClick);
    });
function handleClick()
{
     $(this).siblings().on('click', handleClick);
     $(this).off('click');
     console.log('yeah');
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAFuL/)

Another approach is to make use of `one`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").one('click', handleClick);
});
function handleClick(e)
{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     $(this).siblings().one('click', handleClick);
     console.log('yeah');
}
```

Update to avoid multiple click attached:-

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc8vc/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").on('click', handleClick);
});

function handleClick(e) {
    $(this).off('click').siblings().off('click').on('click', handleClick); //turn off the handler attached to the siblings (during initial load) before attaching it again.

    console.log('yeah');
}
```

Comment: No. Because after that It say 'yeah' 2 times.while I need just one

Comment: +1 for `one`. @haind That is because @PSL is attaching the `handleClick` method to both buttons. Once he clicks either, he attaches `handleClick` once more to the other whilst detaching it from the clicked. Solution is: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('button:first-child').on('click', handleClick); })` without any further changes.

Comment: I'm new.So I can dont' understand `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`. But your answer is something exactly I need. Thank you

Comment: @haind don't worry it is to avoid execution of further events on that element, but i have a fix for it see my update...

Comment: I see. With me it show the same result like the code before.And I try to add button 3, 4.And It's just fine.Thnk!

Comment: Can you explain me why we turn off handler attached to sibling, then attach it again ?

Comment: @haind Sure.. It is because weare already attaching the events to all the buttons in step 1 and on click we attach it to siblings(so it it attached twice) and turn off this one's event. SO eventually 2 click events gets attached to the same element. SO better turnoff the click before attaching.. Thats what i figured...

Comment: Its still complicated for me.I think that Its better if I learn more concept before asking next questions